# SQL Pattern to select only first row from a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has a large number of entries and from which I need only the first in each group.

The table is used to store daily fund prices (1000+ funds) over the last 30 years. I need to find the last price prior to, or on a specific date for each fund existing on that date (so only one row per fund).

In its simplified form, the table has columns **Date**, **FundCode** and **Price**.

The following input

`Date       FundCode  Price
 2016/01/05 X123      1.234
 2016/01/04 X123      1.233
 2016/01/03 X123      1.222
 2016/01/05 A456      1.876
 2016/01/04 A456      1.822
 2016/01/03 A456      1.776
 2016/01/03 M234      3.234`

...when queried for 2016/01/04, should produce

`Date       FundCode  Price
 2016/01/04 X123      1.233
 2016/01/04 A456      1.822
 2016/01/03 M234      3.234`

I have a solution which uses a correlated subquery in the `where` but no amount of messing with indexes will make it run in a reasonable amount of time.

I'm sure there's a straightforward solution to this but I just can't see it.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Also tag the dbms used.

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide sample data, desired results, and the query that you are using.  Also, remember to tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single nested query gives me the max date for each fund, then inner join to this on fundCode/Date, thus...

```
SELECT 
  Date,
  FundCode,
  Price
FROM
  PriceHistory H
    INNER JOIN 

      /* this nested query gives the max date for each fund*/
      (SELECT 
         FundCode,
         max(Date) AS MaxDate
       FROM
         PriceHistory H2
       WHERE
         Date<=@DateToSearchFor
       GROUP BY
         FundCode) AS RowSelector

    ON H.FundCode=RowSelector.FundCode AND H.Date=RowSelector.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like

```
SELECT fundCode, price, date FROM your_table WHERE date<='date_you_need' GROUP BY fundCode HAVING MAX(date)
```

Query like this works in SQLITE, what db do you use?

Comment: Sorry, have just tagged question for SQL Server, and this does not appear to work on SQL Server.